# Deserializing JSON that with key/value fields using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm looking to map some JSON to an Object using Jackson, although the syntax is JSON, it's not a native JSON schema. Normal JSON would have a person data as:

```
{ "name": "Jane", "age": 34}
```

and using Jackson I could reasonably easily map this onto a Java object.

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    Integer age;
}
```

However in my case the JSON is:

```
{ "attributes": [
    { "key": "name", "value": "Jane" },
    { "key": "age", "value": 34 }
]}
```

The actual JSON is more complex and has `attribute` arrays as values as well. Ideally I was looking for a generic solution so I don't have to have custom code for each object I want to map.

My first thought was a custom `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DelegatingDeserializer` that understands this style of JSON.

Does anyone have a good solution to transforming the structure when parsing JSON?

Comment: I think my problem is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73330750/parse-json-array-into-java-classes-using-jackson

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is the creation of a new json file that can be easily converted to your pojo, some considerations about the json you attached to your post here below:

```
{ "attributes": [
    { "key": "name", "value": "Jane" },
    { "key": "age", "value": 34 }
]}
```

Basically this is a `JsonArray` named *attributes* of repeating records in the form of *key, value* entries that can be converted to a map containing just the *key, value* entries. It would less complicated if the all values had the same type, anyway the useful map can be obtained with the creation of an opportune `ObjectNode` with the correct properties:

```
//ok , it is an empty objectnode
ObjectNode objectNode = new ObjectNode(JsonNodeFactory.instance);
//pointing to the attributes array
JsonNode attributes = mapper.readTree(json).at("/attributes");
for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); ++i) {
    //at the first iteration key is "name" and so on...
    String key = attributes.get(i).findValue("key").asText();
    //at the first iteration value is "Jane" and so on...
    JsonNode value = attributes.get(i).findValue("value");
    //setting the "name" property to the "Jane" value in the objectNode
    objectNode.set(key, value);
}

//objectNode is {"name":"Jane","age":34} and can be converted to Person
Person person = mapper.treeToValue(objectNode, Person.class);
```

This solves the initial case you have considered, I don't exclude that in other more complicated cases some modify will be necessary but the code should be substantially remain the same.